# How can I programmatically move a NSWindow to another screen in MacOS Sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift3, fullscreen

I am trying to make a full screen video player that launches on the second monitor, plays a video, and then quits.

I really don't see why this is so hard but I have tried nearly everything I can think of, including everything I find in any answer on SO to do with moving windows or making them full screen.

1) Setting the window frame to the frame of the second screen doesn't move it reliably.

E.g.

```
    if let screen = NSScreen.screens()?[1] {
        let frame = screen.frame
        window.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)
    }
```

May or may not move the window to the second screen. If I set animate: false, it never does.

2) doing self.view.enterFullScreenMode(secondScreen, withOptions: options) doesn't work I end up with a weird floating window on the main screen. If I do enter fullScreenMode  with the main screen it will full screen perfectly.

```
    if let screen = NSScreen.screens()?[1] {

        let presOptions:NSApplicationPresentationOptions = [
            .fullScreen,
            .hideDock,
            .hideMenuBar,
            .autoHideToolbar
        ]

        self.view.enterFullScreenMode(screen, withOptions: [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: presOptions,
                                                            NSFullScreenModeAllScreens: false])
    }
```

Anybody know what the hell I am doing wrong?

I have also attempted window.toggleFullScreen(nil) in applicationDidFinishLaunching - which seems to work on one of my computers but on the other one it runs the app in another space but never sets that space visible.

Comment: How are you creating your window? Does it have the 'fullscreen' flag set? Is it set to be borderless? What window level did you give for it? Is it set to be resizable?

Answer (score 6):

It works for me just using setFrameOrigin e.g.:

```
if let screen = NSScreen.screens()?[1] {
     window.setFrameOrigin(screen.visibleFrame.origin)
}
```

Ref:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483283-setframeorigin

---

Regarding setting window in fullscreen mode. If you are doing it from view (as I think), you could try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.fullScreen)
        self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
        self.view.window?.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow))
    }
```